# Decryption not giving any kind of output in the output file

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

When I want to decrypt the encrypted file the output file is empty.

I have used the following methods of which I call `decryptFile()` in my `main` method. The codes follow:

```java
private static void decryptFile(String outfile, String fileName, String keyName) throws Exception {
        String original = outfile;
        String encrypted = fileName;
        Cipher cipher;
        byte[] iv = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99 };
        SecretKey ks = readKey(keyName, "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        AlgorithmParameterSpec algoSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, ks, algoSpec);
        decrypt(new FileInputStream(encrypted), new FileOutputStream(original), cipher);

    }

    private static void decrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Cipher cipher) throws Exception {
        input = new CipherInputStream(input, cipher);
        writeBytes(input, output);
    }

    private static void writeBytes(InputStream input, OutputStream output) throws Exception {
        byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int readBytes = 0;
        while ((readBytes = input.read(writeBuffer)) >= 0) {
            output.write(writeBuffer, 0, readBytes);
        }
        output.close();
        input.close();

    }

    private static SecretKey readKey(String input, String algo) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
        int kl = fis.available();
        byte[] kb = new byte[kl];
        fis.read(kb);
        fis.close();
        KeySpec ks = null;
        SecretKey key = null;
        SecretKeyFactory kf = null;
        ks = new DESKeySpec(kb);
        kf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(algo);
        key = kf.generateSecret(ks);
        return key;
    }
}
```

I expect the output file to be filled with decrypted text which will be deciphered using the key value already generated and stored in a file by the name `keyname`in a file called `outfile`, but `outfile` is empty.
What could be the problem? I am new to cryptography. What should I do?

Comment: @Andreas I tried that along with a bunch of other things. Maybe I should stop posting questions here before getting the basics under my belt. That way I would not be wasting everybody's time including mine as well. Thanks for giving it a read.

Comment: Getting no output can be caused by multiple problems. If your code throws an exception, you can use that to help pinpoint the problem. But that only works if you make sure the exception stacktrace is printed out. If you catch the exception and do nothing with it then it will appear as though you simply have no output. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk I have outputs in my console. The real problem lies in the decrypted text not being written to the output file.

Comment: And I'm betting the real reason nothing is being written to the output file is because the code you've posted is throwing an exception and somewhere above it you're catching it and then swallowing it silently. So I asked you to verify this. You haven't shown the calling code, so I cannot verify it myself.

Comment: @JamesReinstateMonicaPolk That is precisely it. I have only coded it to print the error message.